# The data entered in the fields doesn't go to database, but I get a success message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this form in a modal with only two fields. I used JavaScript function for PHP script. When I click on Submit, I get a Success Message, but the my database is blank.

```
<?php
require "database_connection.php";
$error = array();



if (isset($_POST['aid'], $_POST['eventList']))
{

    if (empty($_POST['aid']))
        $error[] = 'Please Enter a name';
    else
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO event (Memberid, events) VALUES (?, ?)";
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query))
        {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'is', $_POST['aid'], $_POST['eventList']);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

            echo 'Success';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

JavaScript Submit code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function() {
        $(".submit").click(function(e) {
            var aid = $("#aid").val();
            var eventList = $("#eventList").val();

    var dataString = 'aid='+ aid + '&eventList=' + eventList;
    var data=$('#regPost').serialize()
    if(aid=='' || eventList=='')
    {
        $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
        $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
        console.log("ERROR");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(dataString);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ureg.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(){
                $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
    });
</script>
```

HTML Code for forms:

```
<form method="post" id="regPost" class="registration_form">
    <center>Event Name: <select style="width:200px;" name="eventList" tabindex="5"><br>


                                    <option value="select">Select Event</option>

                                    <optgroup label="X Y Z">

                                      <option value="B Bs">Bas</option>

                                      <option value="Ea">Eas</option>

                                      <option value="So">So</option>

                                    </optgroup>
                                    </select> <br>
    ID:<input type="text" name="aid"><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="submit"></center>
    <span class="error" style="display:none"> Please Enter Valid Data</span>
         <span class="success" style="display:none"> Registration Successfully</span>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not take into account if the query was successful. First, your PHP returns "success" after it attempts to query the database regardless of if it succeeds. You should look into mysqli_errno.

Secondly, your AJAX call assumes a success no matter what the response is. You could return "fail" or even an empty string "" and as long as it comes back with a 200 status header, the success function will fire. Consider adding a failure function on your AJAX call and returning a 400 status code from PHP in the event of failure.

```
http_response_code(400);
```

-- Edit --

This is not something I actually tested, but should get you going in the right direction.

**Server-side:**

```
if (isset($_POST['aid'], $_POST['eventList']))
{

    if (empty($_POST['aid']))
        $error[] = 'Please Enter a name';
    else
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO event (Memberid, events) VALUES (?, ?)";
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query))
        {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'is', $_POST['aid'], $_POST['eventList']);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $error = mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);


            if ( $error ){
                http_response_code(400);
                echo json_encode(array('error' => $error));
            }else{
                http_response_code(200);
            }

        }
    }
}

?>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function() {
        $(".submit").click(function(e) {
            var aid = $("#aid").val();
            var eventList = $("#eventList").val();

    var dataString = 'aid='+ aid + '&eventList=' + eventList;
    var data=$('#regPost').serialize()
    if(aid=='' || eventList=='')
    {
        $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
        $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
        console.log("ERROR");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(dataString);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ureg.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(){
                $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
            },
            error: function(){
                $('.success').fadeIn(200).hide();
                $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Check my edit. I can't debug and test right now but it should get you started

Answer (score 0):

you have written the following code

var data=$('#regPost').serialize();

pass this data in the ajax request instead of datastring as

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ureg.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(){
                $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
            }
        });

Comment: Its still the same.. no changes with the result